# read in timed blocking mode

Tags: c, linux, blocking

how can i make read (or other equivalent function) be in blocking mode for a specific time from the time that function reach execution

or in other words, to wait for an amount of time in which is trying to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Maybe [`alarm`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm) *could* be a viable option for simple cases
- A probably better solution would involve blocking on a [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) (or similar) call with a specified timeout and monitor the file descriptor for reading

Answer (score 0):

Your question is fairly vague, so I can only assume what you mean. I guess you are wanting to attempt to 'read' until a certain deadline or timeout has been reached. In which case, just put the call to the read function inside a while loop which checks the current time against some pre-determined deadline and exits the loop when it has been reached....